# How do I figure out how many bytes are used to store a variable in C using the sizeof operator?

Tags: c, byte, sizeof

We have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LEN 10

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int array[LEN];
    int *p;
    for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }
    for (p = &array[0]; p < &array[LEN]; p++) {
        printf("Address: %p   ", p);
        printf("Value: %d\n", *p);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And it asks us to find out how many bytes the sever uses to store an integer variable, and print it on a newline, and it gives us the hint to use sizeof.

Now, I'm a bit of a noob with pointers, so this is probably a really quick question, but should I print:

```
printf("Size of int: %d", sizeof(p));
```

or `sizeof(*p)`

One prints 4, and the other prints 8. I was leaning toward 8 (which comes from simply p) as it refers to the memory location, not the variable it's pointing to's value, right? And 8 would mean 8 bits, so 1 byte would be the answer?

Comment: `8` does *not* mean 8 bits, it means 8 bytes.

Comment: There is a difference in sizeof(p) and sizeof(*p), the first is the size of the pointer and the other is the size of what the pointer is pointing to. Agree with Andrew Marshall the value returned is bytes not bits and I don't believe the standard allows bits as the defined unit size that will be returned, the size of storage for a pointer is typically the same as the size on an int which is defined as what the operating system can efficiently store and guaranteed to be at least as large as this so typically 4 bytes (32 bits) or 8 bytes (64 bits).

Comment: The parenthesis are redundant. Having `sizeof p` or `sizeof *p` is just as good. You don't use parenthesis in `return(0);` do you?

Comment: Thanks greatly, guys. So just to make sure, the answer would be 4 bytes (or 32 bits), as that's the value for sizeof for the integer, not the pointer?

Comment: The parentheses *are* required when using `sizeof` on a type, though (e.g. `sizeof(int)`).  And some people do use parentheses in `return(0)`.  Barf.

Comment: @DougSmith - that sounds reasonable, yes.  You could check CHAR_BIT to be sure, but machines with non-8-bit bytes are vanishingly rare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution to your particular problem is to use `sizeof` on the type name:

```
sizeof(int)
sizeof(int *)
```

You'll get the answers you need without any confusion.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. Quick additional question then. An initial question asked us to decide the size from the hexadecimal string it gives, how would I go about doing that? The string for one of them, for example, was 0x7fff683a1b7c.

Comment: Hexadecimal string?  What does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not being clear. Here's what it says: "Can you tell how many bytes are used to store an int variable on bluenose? Why?" All we have to go off is a hexadecimal string representing the pointer's address to the array (using %p) and the value of what the pointer is pointing to. The next question asks to use sizeof after we did this.

Comment: Well, the format used by `%p` is implementation specific, so unfortunately no, using its output you can't guarantee anything.  *Most* systems don't even print a full-width zero-padded hex number, so you're probably out of luck in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

p is a pointer to int, so sizeof(p) gives how many bytes a pointer consumes. So the size of an int (your question) you get by

```
sizeof(*p)
```